# centos server anaconda re-install and setting

Tags: python, flask, centos, anaconda

I installed *anaconda3* on *centos* and used the *flask* to run the web project. But an error occurred in anaconda3 library. Only anaconda3 was reinstalled after delete. I set the path to the `.bashrc` file. However, it is not possible to run the flask web project.

Do I need additional settings for my centos server?

Answer (score 1):

Since anaconda already ships with flask, you do not need any additional settings. However, if your project has other requirements like flask extensions e.g. flask-restless etc. then you would need to manually install them using pip.
If your project has a requirements.txt file, you can install the requirements using  `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If it does not have any, then you might have to install a library called pipreqs from the python package index. Then use pipreqs to generate the requirements.txt file and install the dependancies.